# Which Android phones support debugging?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, driver, adb

Which Android phones have ADB drivers to support debugging from Eclipse?

I have a Samsung Infuse phone and was able to debug from Eclipse when I first got it.  A few months ago my phone stopped showing up in Eclipse under devices.  I noticed my ADB driver was gone so I called up Samsung and they said there are no longer ADB drivers for the Samsung Infuse. Has anyone else run into this problem with other phones?

Comment: I got a Galaxy Nexus, Samsung Galaxy S2, HTC Desire and an old Motorola Droid and usb-Debugging works with every Phone. Only for the S2 i must install the Kies-Software which contains the Driver.

Comment: Yea i thought it was really strange when they told me this. I tried installing kies, tried on windows 7 and xp, tried to get old adb drivers, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to use Googles own Nexus devices as they are the best supported for updates and development etc. Plus I prefer to develop without a manufacturer overlay getting in the way.

Never heard of discontinued ADB drivers though. Another plus point for the Nexus line as far as I am concerned. :-)